# Grab current stock price for iPhone app

Tags: ios, finance, stockquotes

How would I be able to have a user enter a stock ticker and using real time data, display the current stock price for that ticker on an iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the free Yahoo! finance CSV api:

https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/YahooFinanceAPIs

this question:

[How to download CSV file from server in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383341/how-to-download-csv-file-from-server-in-objective-c)

and this little tool:

https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

You could grab current stock prices for lots of stocks in one api request and deliver them to your app by parsing the csv.